# How to display images randomly in different image views of gridview with timer in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

i have made the grid view and have all the images in the drawable now what i want is these images come randomly in 9 image view's which i have in grid view, like at 1 second it shows one image as soon as touched by user it dissappears, it displays another image in different image view and it goes on .
Pls Help if any body has the idea . after dis how to make images randomly appear in image view.

```
<
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part of the problem are you having trouble with? Please put some more time into your question.

Comment: hi pls check it i have modified the ques i hope it is more clear to you

Comment: I think Benoir is asking what you did. We can't do the work for you lol.

Comment: i am asking how to implement the randomization of images in grid view using timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to use something like CountDownTimer (or a Handler if you prefer).  I have included an example of how to use the CountDownTimer.  You'll have to use this countdown timer to fire off events as to what is showing (and not showing) and when.  Just off the top of my head, one way to do it would be to put all of your ImageViews (which you should get from your grid's adapter) into an array, and iterate over that array every 5 seconds (using your timer) and determine which ImageViews should be be set to Invisible `setVisibility(View.Invisible)` .

```
**Activity**

// CountDownTimer Example

public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

// Constants
private static final long DURATION = 5 * 1000; // 5 seconds
private static final long INTERVAL = 500; // 500 milliseconds
private static final String FINISHED = "finished";
private static final String CANCEL_MESSAGE = "Timer Cancelled";
private static final long START_TICK_VALUE = 0;
private static final String START = "Start";
private static final String STOP = "Stop";

// Timer
private MyTimer timer;
private long tick;

// UI
private TextView tv;
private Button startButton;
private Button stopButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // start button
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    startButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(this);   
    startButton.setText(START);
    // stop button
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    stopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    stopButton.setText(STOP);
    stopButton.setEnabled(false);

    timer = new MyTimer(DURATION, INTERVAL);
}

// CountDownTimer class
private class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        tv.setText(FINISHED);
        setStartLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        tick += INTERVAL;
        String tickText = String.valueOf(tick);
        tv.setText(tickText);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    // start timer
    case R.id.button1:
        resetTick();
        setStopLayout();
        timer.start();
        break;
    // stop timer
    case R.id.button2:
        timer.cancel();
        setStartLayout();
        tv.setText(CANCEL_MESSAGE);
        break;
    }
}

private void resetTick() {
    tick = START_TICK_VALUE;
}

private void setStopLayout() {
    startButton.setEnabled(false);
    stopButton.setEnabled(true);
}

private void setStartLayout() {
    startButton.setEnabled(true);
    stopButton.setEnabled(false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your case you can just implement the `GridView` with an Adapter, `BaseAdapter` isn't a bad choice. You put the images in 9 random places on your grid. You can use the Random methods in Java in order to get some random behavior. You also set a `onClickListener` on the Grids as well, so when a user clicks it, you pick another random number which will correspond to another spot on the Grid. Bam. I think I put as much work on this answer as you did on the question :)

Oh I just realized you want a timer. Well in that case, check the Java docs for Timer classes. I am pretty sure there are a few options, both native and not. Take your pick. But my implementation remains the same. Everytime the timer goes off, you just refresh the Grid with random Image placement on the grid using Math.random :)

Comment: thanks .. i have posted the code which i am using right now. can u make some changed in it for randomizing images